# Login exist check Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a registration form with angular, but I'm still new to this framework.
I got the password match validation like that:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="uPassword">Password:</label>
    <div>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" Placeholder="Password" id="uPassword" ng-model="user.newPassword" data-ng-class="{'ng-invalid':userForm.pwdConfirm.$error.match}" ng-required="!user.userId"/>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="uConfirm">Confirm: </label>
         <input type="password" data-match="user.newPassword" name="pwdConfirm" Placeholder="Confirm Password" id="uConfirm" ng-model="user.passwordConfirm" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-required="user.userId > 0  && userForm.password.$dirty || !user.userId"/>
         <div ng-show="userForm.pwdConfirm.$dirty && userForm.pwdConfirm.$error.match">Password and Confirm do not match!</div>
 </div>
```

But have problems with checking login availability. This is the input for my login:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="User" name="userLogin" id="uLogin" ng-model="user.login" required/>
</div>
```

already used logins are passed via REST to my UserCreateCtrl controller:

```
    $scope.allUsers = User.all;
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.allUsers.length; i++){
        console.info($scope.allUsers[i].login);
    }
```

Is there any way to use data-match with allUser array somehow like I did with passwords? I'm really stuck at it now.
Thanks for responses,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always prefer the directive way, it give you the ability to control your element with various tools. I use this custom directive for password validation:

```
module.directive('anMatch', function () {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        anMatch: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.$watch(function() {
            return (ctrl.$pristine && angular.isUndefined(ctrl.$modelValue)) || scope.anMatch === ctrl.$viewValue;
        }, function(currentValue) {
            ctrl.$setValidity('match', currentValue);
        });
    }
};
});
```

And the html usage is:

Password:

```
<input type="password" required ng-model="user.password">
```

Confirmed password:

```
<input data-an-match="user.password" type="password" ng-model="user.rpassword">
```

As for the list of users. Again, you can write a custom directive to validate it for you.

```
module.directive('userMatch', ['UserService', function (UserService) {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        anMatch: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.$watch(function() {
            var userExist = true;
            var users = UserService.AllUsers;
            for (i =0; users.lenght; i++) {
                if (ctrl.$viewValue == users[i]) {
                    userExist = false;
                    break;
                }

            }    
            return userExist;
        }, function(currentValue) {
            ctrl.$setValidity('uservalid', currentValue);
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

One last thing, instead of returning username, you might want to MD5 the values on the server and than MD5 the input of the user and match. for security manners.

Read more about [Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and [Angular-MD5](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-md5).

Comment: Thank you, that was very useful and helped me to understand how directives work. TBH I didn't get how to create custom directives from Angular tutorial. Just one more question. Your code for user check was working not like it should. It was enabling me to send form when login was used, and locking when noona was using it. It works more like is login available than user exist and I dont get why. I needed to change the true and false values to their opposites to make it work like it should - if user picks login which is already in database(returned by rest).

Comment: Yeah I can see the mistake now, sorry i've written it here in the comment screen. had to recheck it.

Answer (score 0):

The power of angular js still continually amazes me! Here is a solution with filters.

```
{{(allUsers | filter:user.login:true).length==0?"Unique Name":"Username taken"}}
```

allUsers is the array with all the usernames.

Comment: Exposing all the usernames in your web application to the client seems like a major security risk. While AngularJS is extremely powerful, you want to perform security-sensitive operations server-side rather than client-side.

Comment: I was only responding to the OP's requirement but I agree.